# How to select all child elements of a container via jQuery?

Tags: jquery, containers, parent-child

I need to select all containers, which include tables, divs and iFrames inside of a container. None of the containers inside have ids or classes set.

I tried `$('#google_map > *')` but that didn't do it. Is this even possible?

Comment: No - it's not possible without some HTML. Write some, and then maybe you'll get on faster.

Comment: `$('#google_map').find('*')`?

Comment: @MikeW - Of course, except I'm trying to modify html generated by another site and pasted into my site's option that are end users. I can't ask them to add ids to the html.

Comment: @Tallmaris You should post an answer, because that totally worked and I would accept/upvote said answer. Thanks.

Comment: @JPollock: `$('#google_map *')` would've worked. `>` is the child combinator, so it'll only give you the children of `#google_map`, not the descendants.

Comment: @Blender - looks like I need to learn the difference between children and descendants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best way:

```
$('#google_map').find('*')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple tag selector with this :

```
$("table,div,iframe")
```

[documentation](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.

```
$('html').find('*');
```

In your example, you are using the direct descendant selector, which will only get elements that are directly 'below' `#google_map`, similar to what `children()` will return.

Answer (score 0):

`$(container).children()`  should work